# App is not signed using an Apple submission certificate

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, upload

I was trying to upload my app to app store with no luck,
I have a lot of errors, but now I have only one:

AnimalFace.app is not signed using an Apple submission certificate.
I was trying to do different times. But is not working.

can u help me.

info from apple

Name:AnimalFace
Prefix:NTEP8F44XT
ID:com.animalface.animalface

my config

my actions

1. I generate private key on mac with e-mail (same with my apple account) and enter the name: AnimalFace
2. After that I create certificate on apple.com (distribution) and upload key (at section 1), then download new certificate
3. Create Provisioning Profiles (distribution) an download it
4. Make p12 file by tutorial on build.phonegap.com
5. Then upload p12 and Provision file in to phonegap
6. Generate ipa
7. Use application loader and get error:
   AnimalFace.app is not signed using an Apple submission certificate.

Tell me what`s wrong?
Am was trying to delete all cert. and keys and star but I had same message(

Comment: So you are using phonegap build?

Comment: confirm are you add in target bundle identifier com.animalface.animalface and select you provisioning profile in code signing identity under building setting

Comment: Yes I used phonegap build, and I put in in my confug id like this:

Comment: Yes I do, it was done correct